# Can I query Azure Active Directory (group membership, etc.) from Power BI?

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerquery

I have a service which logs API calls through AppInsights, which I've configured to log the Azure Active Directory (AAD) Service Principal GUID of the authenticated user calling the API. I'd like to use this GUID as a foreign key for lookup in AAD to see which security group the user is in, so I can break down API calls by team. I know this sort of query is possible through AAD's graph REST API, authenticated with an AAD app registration + password (with the Directory.Read.All scope). Is there any way to do this sort of query with Power BI and Power Query?

I know you can connect to on-prem Active Directory through Power BI but I'd rather not have to use a personal gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already are in power bi / query, 
You could create a custom connector that connects to graph api to run your query, 
I think that would directly answer your request?

see here for an example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/samples/mygraph/readme

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I would take a step back and look at design. App Insights is not a conventional data store, the data that is collected is subject to sampling and there are retention policies associated with the telemetry data. Yes you can adjust the sampling settings and the retention policies but App Insights is not really designed for this purpose.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling

I would consider having your application log the principal GUID to a conventional data store like Cosmos DB.

You could then create an Azure function with a timer trigger and collect the information you need from the AAD Graph API into the same Cosmos database.

At that point all of your data is in one place and you can connect to to Cosmos DB from Power BI for reporting.

Comment: I don't see why pushing the API usage data into CosmosDB is really required; this isn't for auditing purposes, it's just a Power BI dashboard.